# This PWM controller appeared to lower Voltage

Tags: pwm

I use the meter and measure output from this PWM controller [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07MK1SKRT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MK1SKRT) and it appeared that the voltage ranging from 0.8V to 2.8V when turning the knob. Is it because this module is not PWM or that how it suppose to work?

Comment: Can you measure with an oscilloscope instead of a multimeter? PWM is supposed to look like a lower voltage for a cheap multimeter.

Comment: @nanofarad oh maybe that why. Yeah sorry I'm noob in this.

Comment: What were you expecting to see?

Comment: Yah, that is how PWM works. You are reading DC equivalent (almost, rms) of PWM duty, An oscilloscope can tell more.